# PHP's realpath equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, php, file

Is there a function in C# equivalent to PHP's [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) for UNIX paths?

I couldn't find any and writing one from scratch seems quite
time consuming.

I know of the [`GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but it has the following problems (for me):

- It's a Windows path that's being returned, so given something like `"//foo//../bar///c"`, `"t:\bar\c"` is returned.
- It removes spaces from directory names, so given something like `"/foo bar/baz"`, `"t:\foobar\baz"` is returned.
- Giving `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath( "//d/"));` doesn't even compile and I get this `ArgumentExcpetion` with message: `The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share.`

Comment: Realpath is for symbolic links and as far as I know, .NET is meant to run on a windows OS. Windows does "support" something similar to symbolic links but I doubt they would support this in C#. So the main question, do you really need to convert a symbolic link?

Comment: @Anyone is "meant"? Actually using Unity I write C# for a wide range of platforms...

Comment: @Anyone: ntfs has symlink support since 2000 I think. also hardlinks and directory junctions. full featured since 2006 (only, but very much existant.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends in what you want and what type of application you're writing in C#

in the `System.IO` there are several path specific function

i.e. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`

You can also get your executing assembly path using reflection
i.e.  `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

In MVC there is the MapPath in the httpcontext
i.e.   `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

There are several options, and most are extensible.

what is your particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Uri` class, it just does not merge all duplicate slashes, so some post-processing is required:

```
new Regex(@"/\/+/").Replace(new Uri("//foo//../bar///c").AbsolutePath, "/")
```

But I would recommend you to code it yourself so you have better control.

Comment: Gives back `/foo/bar///c`, instead of `/foo/bar/c`

Comment: I said that "you get close" only

Comment: Oh yes (missed that). I don't want to get close, I already am close with `GetFullPath`

Comment: I believe you get way closer than with `GetFullPath`. You just need to remove duplicate slashes. I've updated the code for this.

Comment: I have checked it, `Uri` class does NOT replace junctions/links with actual path.